# Student validation failed: image: Path `image` is required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

I have upload image using `node js` with the help of `rest API`, when we upload data and image and postman gives the error like **Student validation failed: image: Path `image` is required.**

My **`Postman Response`** is:

```
{
"errors": {
    "image": {
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "message": "Path `image` is required.",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Path `image` is required.",
            "type": "required",
            "path": "image"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "image"
    }
},
"_message": "Student validation failed",
"name": "ValidationError",
"message": "Student validation failed: image: Path `image` is required."
}
```

My **`schema`** is

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');

const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
 },
 email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: [true, 'Email Id Already Exists..'],
      validate(value) {
           if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
                throw new Error('Invalid Email');
           }
      }
 },
 contact: {
      type: Number,
      min: 10,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
 },
 address: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
 },
 image: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
 }, 

 })

    // we will create a new connection

      const Student = new mongoose.model('Student', studentSchema);
        module.exports = Student;
```

and this is my **`API`**

```
app.post('/students', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {     
 try {
      
      const user = new Student(req.body);
      console.log('req.body');
      const createStudent = await user.save();
      res.status(201).send(createStudent);
 } catch (e) {
      res.status(400).send(e);
 }
});
```

please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using `multer` for uploading files.

After uploading, you'll get the `url` of the file in `req.file`. The data is of the file is not present in `req.body` as far as I've seen in any **file uploader package**

If you are using multer, then you can find it in the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#usage)

You can write your code like this:

```
app.post('/students', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {     
 try {
      
      req.body.image = req.file.path
      const user = new Student(req.body);

      const createStudent = await user.save();
      res.status(201).send(createStudent);
 } catch (e) {
      res.status(400).send(e);
 }
});
```

Comment: ,Sir const user = new Student(req.body,req.file.path); is it ok

Comment: I've updated my answer and added the code. If this helps, then consider accepting my answer

Answer (score 2):

Images are not included in req.body, if you are using multer you will find images in req.file, console log it and then set images to req.file.path to store it into DB

Comment: ,Sir const user = new Student(req.body,req.file.path); is it ok

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const user = new Student({
    ...req.body,
    req.file.path
})
```

Comment: Sir where we add this code ,bcz i new to node

Comment: Add that instead of your initialization: `const user = new Student(req.body)`

Comment: @ Nenad Milosavljevic, Sir I have try this but it gives same message declare in postman response

Answer (score 0):

```
const user = new User({

   name: req.body.name,
   email: req.body.email,
   phone: req.body.phone,
   image: req.file.path

});
```